# Problem with multiple page routing in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I am making an app with has got a welcome and the user page, I used conditions to know when a user is signed in, so I can close login and signup routes, but it doesn't seem to be rendering the pages.

*./App.js*

```
...
componentdidMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => this.setState({auth: user}))
}

render() {
  let Routing;
  if (this.state.auth) {
    Routing = (
      <Route path="/dashboard"><Dashboard /></Route>
    )
  } else {
    Routing = (
      <Route path="/"><WelcomePage /></Route>
      <Route path="/login"><Login /></Route>
      <Route path="/signup"><Signup /></Route>
    )
  }

  return <BrowserRouter>{Routing}</BrowserRouter>
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be because of the typo in the name of the component ? You are trying to render `Rounting` while setting the variable `Routing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put exact to match url

```
Routing = (
      <Route exact path="/"><WelcomePage /></Route>
      <Route path="/login"><Login /></Route>
      <Route path="/signup"><Signup /></Route>
    )
```